# Logging data from multiple WTForms in an sqlite3 database in Flask-Sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlite, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms, wtforms

OK, please help. I'm pulling out my hair even though I know the answer HAS to be something simple.

I have two forms in my Flask-SQLAlchemy web interface project: Post and Survey.

Post was the first page I created to make sure that I can effectively write to the database. It is located on the Home/index page. Logging data from the Home page using the Post class is something I can successfully do.

After creating Post, I wanted to create my first form for my project. This form/class is called Survey. A Survey table exists in my database; I have successfully created all of the columns I need and migrated the table over. I also can see Survey on my webpage.

[image: Top Bar from the Home screen showing Survey]

So let's click on Survey, and sure enough, my form is there.
[image]

Great. OK, now let's add some data.

[image]

I hit submit, and the webpage automatically returns to the home/index screen with the flash message 'Your post is now live!', which is from the Post form not the Survey form. In the terminal, the following code pops up.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Jan/2020 14:59:40] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Jan/2020 14:59:40] "GET /index HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Which is similar to the output I get when I use the Post form.  However, nothing has been saved to my Survey table in the database.

```
>>> Survey.query.all()
[]
```

I can add things to my Post table till I'm blue in the face, but the Survey table doesn't seem to work.  Now I'm sure that this is something stupid. Like, I need to label my submit buttons differently, or perhaps I shouldn't have a form on the index page if I want to use other forms, or I've missed linking the code back to the Home page SOMEWHERE though I've been looking at this code for a couple of days and I can't find it.

Help? My end game is to add *a lot* of these tables to help manage a rather hefty database with a lot of tables and relationships. I can't say that I'm full of confidence if I can't get **two** forms to play nice.

Most of the login code has been removed from below as that's working just fine.

__init__py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect
from config import Config
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_login import LoginManager

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate=Migrate(app,db)
login = LoginManager(app)
login.login_view = 'login'

from app import routes, models
```

forms.py:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField,PasswordField,BooleanField,SubmitField, TextAreaField, DateField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Length

class PostForm(FlaskForm):
    post = TextAreaField('Say something')
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')

class SurveyForm(FlaskForm):
    surveyname=StringField('Survey Name', validators=[DataRequired()])
    surveycode=StringField('Survey Code', validators=[DataRequired()])
    embark=DateField('Date Embark: format=yyyy-mm-dd')
    dock=DateField('Date Return: format=yyyy-mm-dd')
    vessel=StringField('Vessel Name')
    submit=SubmitField('Submit')
```

routes.py:

```
from flask import render_template, flash, request, redirect, url_for
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import current_user, login_user, logout_user, login_required
from werkzeug.urls import url_parse

from app import app, db
from app.models import User, Post, Survey
from app.forms import LoginForm, PostForm, SurveyForm


@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
@app.route('/index',methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def index():
    form=PostForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        post=Post(body=form.post.data, author=current_user)
        db.session.add(post)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Your post is now live!')
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return render_template('index.html', title='Home',form=form)

@app.route('/survey', methods=["GET","POST"])
def survey():
    form=SurveyForm(request.form)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        survey=Survey(surveyname=form.surveyname.data, 
            surveycode=form.surveycode.data, 
            embark=form.embark.data, 
            dock=form.dock.data, 
            vessel=form.vessel.data)                    
        db.session.add(survey)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('survey'))
    return render_template('survey.html', title='Survey', form=form)
```

models.py:

```
from datetime import datetime
from app import db, login

class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    body = db.Column(db.String(140))
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True, default=datetime.utcnow)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Post {}>'.format(self.body)

class Survey(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    surveyname = db.Column(db.String(140), nullable=False)
    surveycode = db.Column(db.String(140), nullable=False)
    embark = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
    dock = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
    vessel = db.Column(db.String(140))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Survey {}>'.format(self.surveycode)
```

Comment: In the survey form's html,  does the `<form>` element have an `action` attribute?  It should contain the url that the form is POSTed to.  If it's empty it will probably POST to `/`.

Comment: AHHHH, Thank you so much. Something simple that I was missing. It was routing back to "/".  It is now writing to the database as easy as I please.